# Time Interval overlap in python

Tags: python, list, datetime, intervals

Suppose I have list of time interval like

```
a = [datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(8,0)]
```

Now I Have lacs of intervals in list like given below.

```
b = [[datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(8,0)], [datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(10,0)], [datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(23,59,59)], [datetime.time(15,0),datetime.time(9,0)], [datetime.time(9,0),datetime.time(15,0)]]
```

We have to filter list b with intervals containing interval a. like in example result will be.

```
b = [[datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(8,0)], [datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(10,0)], [datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(23,59,59)], [datetime.time(15,0),datetime.time(9,0)]]
```

Note: I have changed end time from 00 to 23:59:59 but the case remain persistent as we need to understand that daily interval of 00:00 to 08:00 is contained in interval of 15:00 to 09:00

Hint:
I have divided 15:00 to 09:00 into two intervals: 00:00-09:00 and 15:00-23:59:59

Comment: You mean filter `b`'s element such that `a` is completely contained in the element?

Comment: No, I think what he means is he has a bunch of (start_datetime, duration) pairs and he wants to filter by overlapping time spans.

Comment: Not sure why he's using `datetime.time` instead of `datetime.timedelta` though. Guessing it's an oversight.

Comment: @MuMind actually, I think it's a couple (starting time, ending time).

Comment: @PierreGM: ah, good call. So in that case the oversight is using `datetime` instead of another `datetime.time`... Oh, there, he just updated it.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes @ Mu Mind it's (start time, end time) pairs

Comment: Saw what I wanted to see, I guess. I've had to do almost the same thing, but with (starting datetime, ending datetime) or (starting datetime, timedelta), and respecting timezone info. It was much more complicated.

Comment: I don't understand your example result: how does `[datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(0,0)]` contain `a`?

Comment: Probably he means from hour `0` to `24`... But this makes thing much more complicated, and probably ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has errors (usage of `datetime/datetime.time`).

This code will filter out from `b` everything, that does not overlap with `a`:

```
b = [x for x in b if a[0] < x[1] and x[0] < a[1]]
```

Comment: One or both of those should probably be `<=`, I'd think.

Comment: Does this cover the case in which you have `a = [datetime.time(15,0), datetime.time(9,0)]`, which should mean from 3 pm to 9 am of the next day?[at least, the OP has something like this in the example code]
I don't think so. Probably you should first check whether `a[0] < a[1]` or the opposite and to the filtering accordingly.